# Get SPSS data on notepad?

Tags: spss

I have data in spss.In spss i have that data according to variable.I want that data to write on notepad in the notepad on top row it display variable and under that variable corresponding punches.

Answer (score 1):

Just export the data as a csv file using File > Save As
and choose .csv (, delimiter) or .dat (tab, \t delimiter)  as the type.